# How to set executable file in ROS Qt Creator Plug-in?

Tags: c++, qt, ros

I have installed the ROS Qt Creator Plug-in. I have setup a new ROS workspace with Qt Creator and copied the ROS packages I want to use into it. When trying to run it a pop-up appears stating

> Could not find the executable, please specify one.

I can set a file path, command line arguments and a working directory there.

So what exactly *is* my executable? I initially thought it would be the `main.cpp`, including the main-function of my GUI. I get

> [path] is not an executable file.

Afterwards I tried the *.launch file of the robot simulation I'm working with. Qt Creator seems to accept that as executable but then I get

> The process failed to start. Either the invoked program [path] is missing, or you may have insufficient permissions to invoke the program.

Sorry for the possibly stupid question, I'm kind of new to both ROS and Qt.